# using SELECT INTO with a select as source

Tags: sql, insert

I want to create a table using the results of a query by utilizing SELECT INTO.

The syntax

```
SELECT *
INTO Persons_Backup
FROM Persons
```

is very close to what I want to achieve, with the difference being that I want the FROM to use a query as source.

Something like

```
   SELECT *
    INTO Persons_Backup
    FROM (Select 1, 'a',' 2001-01-01 12:00')
```

does not work, but gives an idea of what I want to do. How can I accomplish this?

I will be using SQL2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your select statement like normal ignoring the `INTO` part.
It should work fine.  For your example:

```
 SELECT 1, 'a',' 2001-01-01 12:00'
    INTO Persons_Backup
```

Or more complicated

```
 SELECT first, last
  INTO person_backup_h
 WHERE first like 'H%'
```

This will also work

```
select 'a' as c1,'b' as c2
 into temp
union all
select 'c','d'
```

Comment: @callisto - example posted for `UNION ALL`